# How to identify a leaf of a tree?

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree

Say I have a tree, with N vertices, and N - 1 edges. The tree is constructed with the data given below. It contains a pair of integers, which represents the vertices that are connected by an edge. The tree is always rooted at 1.

Sample:

> 1 2
>
> 3 1

```
       3
      /
     1
   /  
  2
```

What are the leaf nodes in this example considering the tree is rooted at 1? Is this even a valid tree formation?

Comment: A note about terminology: when discussing trees, we usually use the term "node" rather than "vertex".

Comment: Noted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If 1 is the root, I'd say 2 and 3 are the leaves, but I would rather draw it this way:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
```

or the other way around:

```
2   3
 \ /
  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaf is a node that does not have a child node in the tree. Now coming back to your question :

> Is this even a valid tree formation?

Yes it is a valid tree.

As per the above definition : The leaf nodes in the example (with tree rooted at 1) :

```
       3
      /
     1
   /  
  2
```

Leaf Nodes are : 2 and 3(as two and 3 have no child nodes).

Simple program to check a leaf node :

```
boolean isLeaf(Node node)
{
    if(node == null)       
        return false;
    return node.left == null && node.right == null;      
}
```

Comment: Clearly, `3's` left is 1. So your code will fail saying `3` is not a leaf.

Comment: @AndrewScott Please read description it says that the tree is rooted at 1, dont go by the structure.. So according to it 3 is child of 1, so 3`s left child can never be 1 or we can say that 1 can never be child of 3 :-)